# How to automatically increase javascript item values for local storage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I want to add javascript for local storage so that value of item "firsttimer" increase by 1 each time my website is visited. Any idea how can I do that? Thanking you in anticipation...

```
$(document).ready(function()
  { var isshow=localStorage.getItem(&#39;firsttimer&#39;);
 if (isshow== null) 
{localStorage.setItem (&#39;firsttimer&#39;, 1);}
});

$(document).ready(function()
  { var isshow=localStorage.getItem(&#39;firsttimer&#39;);
 if (isshow== 1) 
{localStorage.setItem (&#39;firsttimer&#39;, 2);}
});

...so on till infinty
```

Comment: localStorage is local to a browser ... so, you want to store how many times a particular person visited your site in their browser?

Comment: Also, `getItem(&#39;firsttimer&#39;)` ... I'm sure you have errors in your browser developer tools console ... try `isShow = isShow +1` after you read it and before you write it

Comment: Jaromanda X, yes, want to store how many times a particular person visited your site in their browser and show them different results depending on their number of visits. For example a welcome message for a person visiting first time, etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use simple `++` instead of hardcore you the number like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  let isshow = localStorage.getItem('firsttimer');
  if (isshow === null) {
    localStorage.setItem('firsttimer', 1);
  }else{
    localStorage.setItem('firsttimer', ++isshow);
  }
});
```

Obviously I don't know how your localstorage is composed or assumed it was just a number and not an array :)

---

Thanks @Jaromanda X for suggest about pre-increment

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that is if isshow is null. What about it being 1, 2 or more? I am a noob in javascript, sorry to bother.

Comment: I correcy my code, if is `null` is always `1` because is first time, else add `1` to `localstorage`

Comment: Thanks a lot, the code is in action, you may check it over here: https://usualqueries.blogspot.com/

Comment: erm ... you mean `++isshow` ... since storing `isshow++` will store 1 when isshow == 1 - therefore, firsttimer can only ever be 1 (or not present before first visit)

Comment: @SohamWani - you can replace all the code inside the document ready with `localStorage.setItem('firsttimer', +localStorage.getItem('firsttimer') + 1);` ... done ... and this will work, unlike the code in this answer

Comment: @SimoneRossaini - 1) dont' assume I downvoted, just because I pointed out your code is wrong, and 2) your code will result in `firsttimer` being set to 1 if it was 1 ... because **post** increment is not what you want, **pre** increment is ... i.e. `localStorage.setItem('firsttimer', ++isshow);` - OP probably fixed your error in real code

Comment: I just looked at the OP's website ... he uses `localStorage.setItem('firsttimer', ++isshow);` because he knows the difference

Comment: Hey ++isshow works and isshow++ doesn't work. Maybe Simone you didn't got what I meant. Both of you, thanks though!

Comment: Hey Jaromanda, can you please check. Whatever written in else is showing even if isshow is null. I am a noob in js. Thanks though!

Comment: I mean the webpushr code should be invisible for null isshow. But it is still visible. Help!

Comment: You don't open `{` in else

Comment: Antoher suggest, you use multiple `$(document).ready(function() {`, instead you can use just one and drop all content into that.

Comment: I told you I am a noob. Thanks!